# WHERE CURDATE() < end_date AND WHERE title LIKE '%test%'

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm building the news site.

I am trying to print only the news that is inside of the right end_date , but some how i cant get it to work

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM p_news WHERE CURDATE() < end_date AND WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";
```

when i try to echo the sql, and test it in phpmyadmin

it get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE title LIKE '%test%' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Should it only have one WHERE clause? e.g. "SELECT * FROM p_news WHERE CURDATE() < end_date AND title LIKE '%$search%'";

Comment: The second WHERE looks a little odd (however I'm no expert in MySQL!). Try 'AND title LIKE '%$search%'";'

Comment: Thank you so much, i was the extra where, that made i not work :) deleted that, and now it works :P ty

Answer (score 1):

It's all [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> ```
> SELECT
>     [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
>       [HIGH_PRIORITY]
>       [MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = N]
>       [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
>       [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
>       [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
>     select_expr [, select_expr ...]
>     [FROM table_references
>       [PARTITION partition_list]
>     [WHERE where_condition]
>     [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
>       [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
>     [HAVING where_condition]
>     [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
>       [ASC | DESC], ...]
>     [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
>     [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
>     [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
>         [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
>         export_options
>       | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
>       | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
>     [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
> ```

In other words, you can have zero or one `WHERE` but never two.

And:

> The WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions
>   that rows must satisfy to be selected. **where_condition is an
>   expression that evaluates to true for each row to be selected**. The
>   statement selects all rows if there is no WHERE clause.
>
> In the WHERE expression, you can use any of the functions and
>   operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (summary)
>   functions. See [Section 9.5, “Expression Syntax”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html), and [Chapter 12,
>   Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one WHERE clause, each condition within that needs to be joined either AND or OR...

```
SELECT * 
FROM p_news 
WHERE CURDATE() < end_date 
AND title LIKE '%$search%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM p_news 
WHERE CURDATE() < end_date 
OR title LIKE '%$search%'
```